# Prepending to a filename

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to prepend something to a dynamically created filename:

```
fstream a;
string f = argv[1];
string  fw = f.substr(0, f.rfind("."));
const char* pre = 'my_';
a.open(pre + fw.c_str(), fstream::out | fstream::in | fstream::trunc);
a.close();
a.open(pre + fw.c_str(), fstream::out | fstream::in | fstream::trunc);
```

But apparently I can't use `+` operator to join this. 
Error :

```
invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char*’ to binary ‘operator +
```

also for the `my_` statement I get

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’
```

Comment: What can't you use the `+` operator? Do you get some sort of error?

Comment: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char*’ to binary ‘operator+, also for the 'my_' statement I get 'invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*

Comment: You cannot concatenate C-strings like that. This is very basic. Which book are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
const std::string pre="my_";
a.open((pre + fw).c_str(), fstream::out | fstream::in | fstream::trunc);
```

Depending on your Compiler and its version, you can even use the following instead (don't need the `.c_str()` part).

```
a.open(pre + fw, fstream::out | fstream::in | fstream::trunc);
```

Comment: No need for the `.c_str()`; we're in 2015.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the info! I've updated the answer. Which version of `g++` first support not using  `.c_str()`?

Comment: You may look that up in the documentation. GCC isn't the only toolchain, y'know...

Answer (score 2):

You know about `std::string`, now why would you use `const char*`? Even the initialization is wrong:

```
const char *pre = 'my_'; // must be double-quoted
```

Then, if you want to concatenate two `const char*`, instead of adding pointers together, you need to use [`std::strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat):

```
char fname[100] = "my_"; // You decide the length of the buffer, it would be MAX_PATH on Windows
a.open(std::strcat(fname, fw.c_str()), fstream::out | fstream::in | fstream::trunc);
```

You can also use `operator+` on `std::string` and `const char*`, which is a lot simpler:

```
const char *pre = "my_";
a.open(pre + fw, fstream::out | fstream::in | fstream::trunc);
```

**But that is not how you should do it**. Use `std::string`s only:

```
fstream a;
string f = argv[1];
string  fw = f.substr(0, f.rfind("."));
std::string pre = "my_";
a.open(pre + fw, fstream::out | fstream::in | fstream::trunc);
a.close();
a.open(pre + fw, fstream::out | fstream::in | fstream::trunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
pre + fw.c_str()
```

to

```
(string(pre) + fw).c_str()
```

Or even better to stay with C++ string:

```
string(pre) + fw
```

Also please note that you incorrectly defined the constant C style string:

```
 const char *pre='my_';
```

it should be:

```
 const char *pre="my_";
```

Comment: The cast is unnecessary.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is not casting. It's a call for `string` constructor which is done anyway by the compiler in this case but with `string(pre)` it is clearer in my opinion.

Comment: I'm afraid you are mistaken. It _is_ a cast. It is called "functional cast notation". You never, ever directly "call a constructor"; that's impossible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know that I never directly call a constructor. After googling about "functional cast notation" seems that you are correct. That was what I meant but I didn't know that it is also considered to be `cast`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Never mind :) I got in my mind C style cast and ''static/dynamic/reinterpret" casts... For some reason I didn't consider `Type(var)` to be casting... I admit, my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `string` for `pre` as well, something like:

```
string pre = "my_";
//  then pre + fw
```